# Universal Color Selection Tool

Tags: rgb, colors

I need to find the RGB of a color that is on an emulator.

I need an app that can get the RGB from a separate application.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be what you're looking for.
http://download.cnet.com/Pixie/3000-10247_4-10047496.html?tag=mncol

If not, can you take a screencap and crop the section of color you want to find.  Then upload it to photobucket or something and use this web tool:
http://www.degraeve.com/color-palette/

Comment: Yep, Pixie's (http://www.nattyware.com/pixie.php) a great little utility. Let's you zoom in (Ctrl + Alt + Z) too.